# Solving a set of Linear Equations with varying coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-regression

Let $Y_{N\times1} = A_{N \times N}X_{N \times M}W_{M \times 1} + N_{N\times 1}$, where $A$ is a diagonal matrix with the elements $a_{i,i}$ being a function of array index ($a_{i,i} = k_0k^i$, where $i$ is the row/column index of the diagonal matrix $A$ and both $k_0$ and $k$ are uknown scalar values), $X$ is the input matrix and $W$ is the coefficient vector and $N$ is the noise vector, with a $0$ mean unit variance Gaussian pdf.

$Y$ is the output vector. Given $Y$ and $X$ are known, is there a way to solve for both $A$ and $W$, provided N > M+1 ?

For a general set of linear equations $Y = XW + N$, I can solve using Least Squares, as long as M <=N, but I am not sure how to solve the above, where we have an additional coefficient matrix $A$, (although it adds just 1 extra unknown, i.e. '$k$').
Thanks!

Comment: "with the elements forming a straight line equation" What?

Comment: Numbers cannot form an equation. Also you need to use LaTeX

Comment: I am sorry I did not understand that. Here, the elements of A are a function of col/row index, which is the independent variable and k, which is the slope. I tried telling the relation between matrix index and the elements of A. May be there is a better way to formulate it.

Comment: The unknown scalar $k$ cannot be separated from the solution for $W$, or to put it differently, the scalar $k$ can be lumped in with $W$ (while the ascending diagonal matrix $\operatorname{diag}(1,2,\ldots,N)$ gets premultiplied onto the known input matrix $X$.  In that sense the "additional coefficient matrix $A$" is illusory.

Comment: Thanks @hardmath, unfortunately I would need the estimate of k as well as W, since they have separate physical meanings in the context, where the model is applied. $W$ is the precoding weights and $A$ is the phase matrix due to timing error. Also, $W$ has a different dimension than $A$. In absence of $A$, $W$ would be simply telling me how do I combine multiple $X$ vectors to get $Y$. $A$ on the other hand is telling me in the presence of a timing slip, what is the additional phase on $Y$. (I replaced elements of $A$ here  rather than giving a full expression, just for the sake of simplicity)

Comment: @hardmath I think I had made a typo, hence I failed to simplify the problem correctly. Instead of $ki$ I intended to write $k^i$. I have corrected it, sorry for the confusion and giving you trouble! As you would see now that it is a bit more tricky. Ideally the phase is given by $exp(j2\pi n_0 k/N)$ where $n_0$ is the timing slip and  $k$ is the index of each element of vector $Y$, hence the original formulation was incorrect. Sorry again, and thanks for your time!

Comment: You should correct the problem statement, which still says $A$ is a diagonal matrix whose entries are "scalar multiple of array index".  Your Comment above also makes this claim, " that a(1,1) = k , a(2,2) = 2k, and so on."  Indeed the problem setup is not clear, in that while input $X$ and output $Y$ are "known", it is unclear whether you work with only a single such observation or multiple observations.  The notion of $N$ as "noise" suggests some probability distribution should be modelled for these errors, if linear regression is to be applied.

Comment: @hardmath, thanks for pointing it out. I reformulated the problem statement, and deleted the misleading comment too.

Comment: Thanks, but I think the introduction of $k_0$ is of little value, whether it is a known or an unknown.  Either way that scalar factor can be propagated over into $W$ as we previously discussed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not well determined.  Evidently you have in mind some linear regression procedure similar to how one might estimate the solution to the seemingly simpler equation:

$$ Y = XW + N $$

with the interpretation that "the noise vector" N will be minimized.

Your altered equation:

$$ Y = AXW + N $$

introduces a diagonal matrix $A$ whose diagonal entries form a geometric series.  Various statements about the parameterization of $A$ were made, but in each case we have $A$ invertible for any nonzero choice for parameter $k$.

Notice that if $k\neq 0$, multiplying both sides on the left by $A^{-1}$, it becomes:

$$ A^{-1} Y = XW + A^{-1}N $$

Now one can apply the linear regression you proposed for the simpler problem setup, solving for matrix $W$ and noise vector $N$.  In other words you can apply whatever choices for $A$ you prefer (so long as it is invertible), and settle for solutions $W,N$ provided by the earlier procedure.

Of course one might object that this does not minimize the objective function you intended for $N$, but repeated requests for clarification did not elicit any information about that criteria or the underlying probability model.

Think carefully about what motivates your problem.  I'm convinced you have a real motive (application) but have not thought through what essential characteristics would determine the "best" $A$.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time @hardmath, it is much appreciated! The only issue which I had to the solution is $A$ is unknown because $k$ as well as $k_0$ which is a non zero value are not known. So I am not sure how do I apply a $A^-1$ in absence of that information. But I agree with the rest, that in case they are known, the problem turns into a trivial Least Squares problem. I am not sure what information related to $A$ would be further helpful. I had indicated in one of the comments, the application is in determining the time delay/slip, and they form that structure. But thanks again!

Comment: My larger point is that you ask to determine more unknowns than you have known data.  You should explain whether your have a sequence of inputs and outputs $X,Y$, but if you have only one (as your notation suggests), then $A,W$ can be chosen arbitrarily, and you can take $N = Y - AXW$.  Presumably you not only considered having multiple inputs & outputs, but also *minimizing* in some unspoken way the (expected) value of $N$.  This needs to be setup up in the body of your Question in order for Readers to help with the underlying application.

Comment: Perhaps I did not clarify well enough, $Y$ can be a vector of 2048 elements, hence $A$ a matrix of 2048x2048  diagonal matrix, $X$ is a matrix of 2048x4 and $W$ is a vector of 4x1. I think I tried to write that the vector size of $Y$ is larger than $W$ (N>M) but perhaps numerical examples would have clarified.

Comment: Numerical examples would help both of us.  Readers can probably only digest smallish examples, but feel free to email me (username at gmail) a realistic example.  There is a straighforward "nonlinear" regression for your equation, but it will help if the *objective* function (minimizing $N$) can be articulated.  Per your last Comment, $N$ would be the same size as $Y$.

Comment: The objective function would be to minimize $\mathbf{E}[(Y - \hat{Y})^2]$, where $\hat{Y}$ is given by $\hat{Y} = \hat{A}$X$\hat{W}$, where $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{W}$ are parameters to be estimated. Yes, you are right, $N$ is of the same length of $Y$.  Please treat $N$ noise as negligible, if it causes complication. Regarding numerical examples, any random set of $k$, $k_0$, $W$ and $X$ would do, N = 6, M = 4 would be good too, as an example. Since I do not have data either, I am trying to work with symbols instead of real numbers, to find a general solution, although no luck so far.